# Join sql tables to select records which does not exists in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I join tables to select records which do not exist in the joined table.
E.g. I have a table documents, students, folders

I’m developing student payment system therefore I would like to select students which have not paid on a certain semester

1.Table students and documents can be joined at student.student_id

2.Table folders stores semester it can be joined with documents at folder.folder_id

Comment: Or you could have googled "Join sql tables to select records which does not exists."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All students that does not exist in documents table:

```
select 
  students.*
from
  students
left join
  documents on documents.student_id = students.student_id 
where
  documents.document_id is null
```

For choosing the semester it's a bit trickier but it has the same logic:

```
select 
  students.*
from
  students
left join
  (
   select documents.* from documents 
   inner join folders on folders.folder_id = documents.folder_id
   where folders.folder_id = 3
   ) as t1 on t1.student_id = students.student_id 
where
  t1.document_id is null
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/544ea/6)

You can look/read this [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thanks, The second one works fine

Answer (score 2):

Use an `LEFT JOIN` construct, and look for rows where the table you'd like to be missing have NULL data.

For your particular example, something like:

```
SELECT Student.Student_id
FROM Student
    LEFT JOIN Documents ON Student.Student_id = Documents.Student_id
WHERE Documents.Student_id IS NULL
```